# Derivative of different variables and using chain ruleb

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

> Suppose $\phi(x)$ is defined by a formula in which x occurs in several
> places (for example, there are three $x$’s in $\phi(x)=
> > \frac{x^2e^x}{x+3}$).
>
> Show that the derivative $\phi'(x)$ is obtained by differentiating
> with respect to each of the $x$’s in turn, treating the others as
> constants, and adding the results.
>
> Hint: Let $F(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ be the function of several variables
> obtained by replacing each of the $x$’s in the formula for $\phi(x)$
> by a different variable.

I need to Express $\phi$ in terms of F and use the chain rule. Now i am having trouble in proving that $\phi'(x)$ is actually the sum of partial derivatives of the function. And therefore cant really reach to a conclusion for this question. The answer in the text book was given the following

````
E“_  E“?ŽY“?ŽLŽY“_```
````

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer

Comment: Are you familiar with Frechet derivative?

Answer (score 1):

The multivariable chain rule says that if you assume each variable $x_i = x_i(t)$ is a function of another variable $t$, then the total derivative is

$$ \frac{dF}{dt} = \sum_i \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} \frac{dx_i}{dt} $$

If you take $x_i(t) = t$ for all $i$, then $\frac{dx_i}{dt} = 1$, and so you get that $\frac{dF}{dt}$ is the sum of the partial derivatives (with $x_i = t$ substituted).